# Here traffic api closed roads

Tags: traffic, here-api

I am searching for the latitude/longitude of closed roads.
If I use http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&quadkey=12020330
I get all warnings with geolocations and flag if the road is closed... but
these geolocations are not precise. On here maps you can see the black lines(the closed roads)
I only need these latitudes/longitudes (of the vertex or only inside of the street and the direction).
At the moment I think the only way to get these coordinates is to ask for the closed roads and get pictures of these areas. And with these pictures we can calculate the geolocation.
But to check all pictures of all closed roads is computationally intensive.
does somebody have a better idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `flow` endpoint as described [here](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/resource-parameters-flow.html) supports an additional `responseattributes` parameter, this can add the shape and functional class of the road in question. e.g.

- [http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?quadkey=QUADKEY&responseattributes=sh,fc&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&minjamfactor=7](http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?quadkey=0313131311102300330&responseattributes=sh,fc&minjamfactor=7&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

The `incidents` endpoint returns data in an industry standard [Traffic_message_channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_message_channel) format - this is designed to minimize data sent and therefore does not give exact locations.

- [http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&bbox=LAT,LNG;LAT,LNG&criticality=critical](http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&bbox=52.5311,13.3644;52.5114,13.4035&criticality=critical)

Try combining data from them both to get complete traffic information - i.e. road shapes and incident data. I guess for closed roads you are looking at a `minjamfactor=7` or greater.